# Audio cuts off completely when using bluetooth headphones?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

So, I started having this really annoying problem when using my bluetooth headphones. I tried looking for answers everywhere but either no one has encountered the same issue, or my english doesn't let me word a good enough search to get to it.

What happens is that while the headphones are connected but I'm not playing any audio and then I try to play something no sound is played. The weird thing about that is that not only does the sound cut, but whatever media player (be it a desktop application or a web page) that I'm trying to use also stops, what I mean is, that in YouTube for example when I press play the player starts 'buffering' but it just doesn't even start, same happens with any other media player. I also don't get any system sounds nor any sound at all, it's like all audio related things just stop working due to this.

It's a really frustrating problem, since I can be watching some video or listening to a song, and if I pause it for a moment when I try to resume watching the issue happens.

What I do to solve this, is just turn bluetooth communication off and on, but it's definitely not a permanent fix, since I have to do it so many times.

I'm kind of afraid of messing with drivers, and I don't want to try that unless I have a good clue of what's causing this since I can't find any information on it. I found someone having a similar problem on Ubuntu, but my laptop runs Windows 10.

I'd be very thankful for your help, since silly me has been just living with it for a few months. Like seriously I'm studying software engineering and I'm afraid to meddle with my computer in fear of losing information.

My computer:
Model: E5-521-64LM
Windows 10
Acer
AMD A6 Quad-Core 1.8 Ghz
6 GB RAM
(I don't know what else could be relevant)

Headphones:
URBAN-T BT592(Pretty sure they're just reselling Beyution BT592 since they're identical). They're no exactly expensive ones, but they're pretty good.

Comment: Sounds like either the headphones or your BT adapter on the PC side is dropping into a low-power mode and failing to wake up properly from it. Unfortunately, there's probably not much you can do other than try changing hardware, try disabling the low-power mode (but then the headset can't go into standby and the battery will drain much quicker even when not playing), or keep going with your current workaround.

Comment: Please provide the exact model of your computer and the exact model of your bluetooth headset. Don't provide this info in comments. Please [edit] your post to improve it.

Comment: Done. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem, just so you know you're not alone... mine also occasionally happens while actively listening to video, with several different headsets (better quality ones than yours, like the BeoPlay H8 and Beats Solo3 Wireless). I think the key to the problem is in the Windows Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Interesting allquixotic, the worst thing the problem has caused is that it once happened while playing a videogame and it crashed completely, So, it's pretty bad an weird how that messes with how the programs run, instead of just running mute.